# Correct DB details produce “Database server was not found” (Prestashop Installation)

Tags: mysql, web-platform-installer, prestashop

At stage 3 of the Prestashop Installation, I enter the DB details which I know to be correct, and I receive the error:

> Database server was not found. Please
>   verify the login, password, and
>   database server name fields.

The server is localhost, and I have verified the database name and username. Why can Prestashop not find the server?

This occurs when choosing InnoDB and MyIsam.

If I change the server from localhost to the public hostname I receive the same error.

Comment: 1) Double check that you can actually login into DB using those details (you may have correct login/database in place, but, probably, username was set up in such way that it not allowed to connect from that address); 2) Please check if you can connect to that DB from within PHP (create some simple test PHP script) -- maybe you do not have required extensions enabled; 3) Firewall? (don't think so .. but); 4) Server address: try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`.. or you may need to specify some another name (linux socket?) -- consult your hoster for exact details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated a 2nd user account, which tested okay.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful about the collation settings of the database you created. Collation must be `utf8_general_ci` for database Prestashop. Otherwise you receive connection error.

Answer (score 1):

Despite WAMP supposedly using root/root as the default, the MySQL uses root/[no password]. Silly Prestashop error about database server is not found, is actually just a logon problem.

Answer (score 1):

- First create new db in phpmyadmin.
- For the user, keep it root.
- Just leave password as blank.  You can change it later once successfully installed.
- Click on "test db"

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because I use Prestashop with Docker.

> Using the container name as the host solves this problem.

Comment: Although this problem has passed for a long time, this problem still exists.Hope it will be useful for future friends.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the members' area, enter the control panel and click on the 'MySQL' icon.
Your MySQL hostname / username / database name etc will be listed there.

Also make sure you use the correct hostname, **not** localhost.

Comment: The OP has already stated that the correct hostname **is** localhost and that the problem was related to the user and not the database connection.